How to handle opening a file with your program with Python?
I am currently doing a simple Tic-tac-toe project with Python. I want to develop a new feature: "Save and Load game". I can format the game into the things I want and save them to a file, then load it if the user needs it. However, all of those processes are only in my game. I wonder if I go to the "Properties" of my file (with a weird extension) then set "Open with" as my program, then how can I actually handle it and load the game? I've research on Google but look like I didn't got the correct keyword (It said things about uploading files and loading files with Python, which I've done earlier).
Please help me with this. Thank you

"I didn't got the correct keyword and it keeps showing something else.". We cannot guess what you have done, what keyword you are referring to, or what that "something else" is. Please edit your question and add full details of what you have done and what is not working.

First, you need to read  arguments in your python script:
import sys

save_file = sys.argv[1]
print(f'Open save file: {save_file}')

Second, you need to convert you python script to exe (you can use auto-py-to-exe)
Finally, you can do open with with your exe file and you'll get save file path:
Open save file: D:\PROGRAMMING\temp\so\78424804\1.save

